# How to prevent mouse button 4 from triggering the "back" action on macOS?

Tags: macos, mouse, mouse-click

When using mouse button 4 (or mouse button 5) on macOS as, for example, a push-to-talk button, every browser, the Finder, System Preferences etc. go back (or forward) after release.

It's extremely annoying and I haven't found any solution to this problem yet.

Is it possible to disable going back and forward when using those buttons?

Comment: How do you have your mouse settings set in the Mouse panel of System Preferences? Or if you're using a third-party mouse that comes with its own software, how do you have that set up?

Comment: Mouse doesn't have software for MacOS and in System Preferences there are no detailed settings available (there are only speed of scrolling, doubleclick etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 3rd party mouse driver.

[USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com) & [Steermouse](https://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) are the two most commonly used.
Personally, I've always preferred Steermouse, though it's twice the price.
Both are capable of far more than just reassigning a button. Try both for a while & see which you prefer [though you can't have both installed at once].

Comment: Thanks! With the help of your answer, I found Mac Mouse Fix, a free program that works just as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

[Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) can do this. The following script disables mouse buttons 4 and 5 (*buttonNumber* 3 and 4 in the code).

Create `~/.hammerspoon/mouse.lua`:

```lua
local module = {}

local eventtap = require "hs.eventtap"
local event    = eventtap.event

local mouseButtonHandler = function(e)
    local buttonNumber = e:getProperty(event.properties.mouseEventButtonNumber)
    if buttonNumber == 3 or buttonNumber == 4 then
        return true  -- consume the event (disabling it)
    else
        return false -- do nothing to the event, just pass it along
    end
end

module.mouseButtonListener = eventtap.new({ event.types.otherMouseDown }, mouseButtonHandler)

module.start = function()
    module.mouseButtonListener:start()
end

module.stop = function()
    module.mouseButtonListener:stop()
end

module.start() -- autostart

return module
```

Add the following to `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua`:

```lua
mouse = require("mouse")
```

Reload your Hammerspoon config for the mouse buttons to be disabled.

Comment: Please motivate your downvotes.